# SqlAlchemy problem in Virtual Environment: cannot import name 'inspect' from 'sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, virtualenv

I've been using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04) tutorial to setup flask on ubuntu server.
It worked fine for one project, now I try to setup it on the other one.
This time the app works fine without SQLAlchemy, but once I use it, it gives 'Internal server error'.

- checked the installation of flask_sqlalchemy - looks fine
- made sure I don't have a file named 'sqlalchemy'
- I can launch the app with sqlalchemy but without virtualenv, it works fine!
- I double-checked that flask_sqlalchemy has the same configuration in virtualenv library, as in the python library

error that I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myproject2.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
  File "/root/myproject2/myprojectenv2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalch                                       emy/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import event, inspect, orm
ImportError: cannot import name 'inspect' from 'sqlalchemy' (/root/myproject2/my                                       projectenv2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/__init__.py)
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: what happens if you just import `sqlalchemy` from a python repl (prompt) inside the virtualenv, and then print/inspect it?

Comment: @2e0byo 

1) I type 'python3'
2) type 'import sqlalchemy
3) type 'print (sqlalchemy)'
4) and get this:

<module 'sqlalchemy' from '/root/myproject2/myprojectenv2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/__init__.py'>

Comment: right, so you're definitely gettings sqlalchemy.  can you `from sqlalchemy import inspect` in the repl? [Update the question with this, because it narrows down where teh problem is happening].

Comment: Incidentally you *really don't* want to run your webserver as root.  You want to run it as another system user made specially for the task, with no write permissions outside /var/www or wherever you're keeping any files the server needs to write.  NB this has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: I type: 'import inspect from sqlalchemy' and get:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import inspect from sqlalchemy
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking in the wrong language, sorry... `from sqlalchemy import inspect`

Comment: noted on the user suggestion!

Comment: used: 'from sqlalchemy import inspect' and got: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'inspect' from 'sqlalchemy' (/root/myproject2/myprojectenv2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/__init__.py)

Comment: Try `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall flask-sqlalchemy sqlalchemy` inside the venv.  Something is broken in your setup (but at least we know it's the venv). Post any errors you have

Comment: Oh, and add how you *made* the venv to the question (so we don't have to trawl through a tutorial), and how you then installed.  there are a few ways of doing venvs

Comment: wow, thank you very much! it worked!! If I can select your comment as a right answer, I'd be happy to!

Comment: oh good.  I've converted it to an answer so it's easier to see next time; you can select that if you want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your installation is broken in the virtualenv.  Try reinstalling by running this from within the virtualenv:

```py
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall flask-sqlalchemy sqlalchemy
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into same problem but with different kind of issue. While upgrading to recent flask_sqlalchemy and sqlalchemy libraries, I have noticed that construct has been changed from:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import inspect
```

this got broken, and new construct is:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
```

just want to state something that may be easily overseen

---

apart from that the issue may be wrong libraries in venv on specific installations

I have system python 3.10 however I run app under python 3.7 for compatibility reasons. On that line, I have noticed that it is easy to mix python library versions and get 3.10  library under 3.7 venv - pay attention during installation of SQL libraries - pip may go wild.

---

hope these hints help someone as these issues drove me nuts for days